# How to wait subscriber to complete before onNext?

Tags: c#, .net, reactive-programming, system.reactive, rx.net

I am very new to reactive programming and I stuck at one point.

I try to implement if my collection has reaches a certain number element or certain time has paseed i need to trigger some method.

Purpose of use: I will process the events coming from the database, but I need to mark where I left off after every 200 events OR save last processed event every 10 seconds because maybe there won't be an event to reach 200 for a long time. But OnNext do not wait finish saveCheckPoint method and continue acepting processed item. I need to wait in before OnNext to sake of data consistency.

To simulate my design you can check this code, how can i achieve my requirement?

```cs
Subject<string> events = new Subject<string>();

events
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), 200)
    .SelectMany(async x => await SaveCheckpoint(x)).Subscribe();


async Task<bool> SaveCheckpoint(IList<string> i)
{
    var lastProcessedEvent = i.LastOrDefault();

    if (lastProcessedEvent != null)
    {
        //Save checkpoint to db or somewhere else
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine($"Saved checkpoint of : {lastProcessedEvent}");
    }
   
    return await Task.FromResult(true);
}


for (int j = 1; j < 10000; j++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Event processed");
    // I need this step must be wait until subscriber to comlete task
    events.OnNext($"Event - {j}");
}
```

I am expecting to find a way to wait complete of Subscribe method before onNext

Comment: Are you sure you are not swimming against the flow here? Rx nearly always introduces concurrency due to its nature and only very weird requirements need you to specify a mutually exclusive scheduler. So, I would expect to have the buffering happen in parallel to any other processing from earlier windows.

Comment: @TanveerBadar Despite you're right I cannot agree with you :-)  Since Rx' behavior is single-threaded by default (with some obvious exceptional operators) I personally always try to get code working in single-thread mode and only then to introduce concurrency - IF the concurrency isn't in the initial requirements

Comment: Unrelated: afaik you should `using` the `IDisposable` that you get from `Subscribe`.

Comment: Why do you expect `OnNext` to block? It is completely unrelated to the subscriber and that is by design. That way the producer can stay _reactive_ ... at least so I thought.

Comment: @TanveerBadar i think you are right, i just want to trigger my checkpoint  when buffer is full Or certain time passed and i thought maybe Rx can help me.
I will consider solve my problem much simpler structures maybe like concurrent collections + thread safe timers

Comment: @OlegDok - Rx is not single-threaded by default. Each operator has a threading model that is specifically set in that operator. In other words, there is a threading default per operator.

Comment: @OsmanAktemur - Don't ever do `async x => await ` in Rx operators. It's like having `async void` it's dangerous. Always do `.SelectMany(x => Observable.FromAsync(() => SaveCheckpoint(x))`. It won't help here, but it's always the way to go.

Comment: And what's the point of doing `return await Task.FromResult(true);` when `return true;` would work?

Comment: The issue here with this code isn't anything to do with Rx. It's the `async Task<bool> SaveCheckpoint(IList<string> i)` method you're calling. They are designed to let the calling code continue - which it does - and you're at the mercy of the `Task` scheduler. Take out the `async` and just do `bool SaveCheckpoint(IList<string> i)` with a `.Select(x => SaveCheckpoint(x))` and it works fine.

Comment: Don't mix monads. Either stay in the `Task<T>` world or stay in the `IObservable<T>` one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me you need to do it without async/await execution, like this:

```
static async Task Main()
{
    void TimestampedPrint(object o) => Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH.mm.ss.fff}: {o}");
    Subject<string> events = new Subject<string>();

    using var disposable = events
        .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 20)
        .Subscribe(x => SaveCheckpoint(x).GetAwaiter().GetResult());


    async Task SaveCheckpoint(IList<string> i)
    {
        var lastProcessedEvent = i.LastOrDefault();

        if (lastProcessedEvent != null)
        {
            //Save checkpoint to db or somewhere else
            await Task.Delay(100);
            TimestampedPrint($"Saved checkpoint of : {lastProcessedEvent}");
        }
    }


    for (int j = 1; j < 100; j++)
    {
        TimestampedPrint($"Event processed {j}");
        // This do not wait subscriber to finish batch
        events.OnNext($"Event - {j}");
    }

    TimestampedPrint("End");

    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

This produces the following output:

```
12.54.50.657: Event processed 1
12.54.50.693: Event processed 2
12.54.50.693: Event processed 3
12.54.50.693: Event processed 4
12.54.50.693: Event processed 5
12.54.50.693: Event processed 6
12.54.50.693: Event processed 7
12.54.50.693: Event processed 8
12.54.50.693: Event processed 9
12.54.50.693: Event processed 10
12.54.50.693: Event processed 11
12.54.50.693: Event processed 12
12.54.50.693: Event processed 13
12.54.50.693: Event processed 14
12.54.50.693: Event processed 15
12.54.50.693: Event processed 16
12.54.50.693: Event processed 17
12.54.50.693: Event processed 18
12.54.50.693: Event processed 19
12.54.50.693: Event processed 20
12.54.50.807: Saved checkpoint of : Event - 20
12.54.50.808: Event processed 21
12.54.50.808: Event processed 22
12.54.50.808: Event processed 23
12.54.50.808: Event processed 24
12.54.50.808: Event processed 25
12.54.50.808: Event processed 26
12.54.50.808: Event processed 27
12.54.50.808: Event processed 28
12.54.50.808: Event processed 29
12.54.50.808: Event processed 30
12.54.50.808: Event processed 31
12.54.50.808: Event processed 32
12.54.50.808: Event processed 33
12.54.50.808: Event processed 34
12.54.50.808: Event processed 35
12.54.50.808: Event processed 36
12.54.50.808: Event processed 37
12.54.50.808: Event processed 38
12.54.50.808: Event processed 39
12.54.50.808: Event processed 40
12.54.50.909: Saved checkpoint of : Event - 40
12.54.50.909: Event processed 41
12.54.50.909: Event processed 42
12.54.50.909: Event processed 43
12.54.50.909: Event processed 44
12.54.50.909: Event processed 45
12.54.50.909: Event processed 46
12.54.50.909: Event processed 47
12.54.50.909: Event processed 48
12.54.50.909: Event processed 49
12.54.50.909: Event processed 50
12.54.50.909: Event processed 51
12.54.50.909: Event processed 52
12.54.50.909: Event processed 53
12.54.50.909: Event processed 54
12.54.50.909: Event processed 55
12.54.50.909: Event processed 56
12.54.50.909: Event processed 57
12.54.50.909: Event processed 58
12.54.50.909: Event processed 59
12.54.50.909: Event processed 60
12.54.51.007: Saved checkpoint of : Event - 60
12.54.51.007: Event processed 61
12.54.51.007: Event processed 62
12.54.51.007: Event processed 63
12.54.51.007: Event processed 64
12.54.51.007: Event processed 65
12.54.51.007: Event processed 66
12.54.51.007: Event processed 67
12.54.51.007: Event processed 68
12.54.51.007: Event processed 69
12.54.51.007: Event processed 70
12.54.51.007: Event processed 71
12.54.51.007: Event processed 72
12.54.51.007: Event processed 73
12.54.51.007: Event processed 74
12.54.51.007: Event processed 75
12.54.51.007: Event processed 76
12.54.51.008: Event processed 77
12.54.51.008: Event processed 78
12.54.51.008: Event processed 79
12.54.51.008: Event processed 80
12.54.51.108: Saved checkpoint of : Event - 80
12.54.51.108: Event processed 81
12.54.51.108: Event processed 82
12.54.51.108: Event processed 83
12.54.51.108: Event processed 84
12.54.51.108: Event processed 85
12.54.51.108: Event processed 86
12.54.51.108: Event processed 87
12.54.51.108: Event processed 88
12.54.51.108: Event processed 89
12.54.51.108: Event processed 90
12.54.51.108: Event processed 91
12.54.51.108: Event processed 92
12.54.51.108: Event processed 93
12.54.51.108: Event processed 94
12.54.51.108: Event processed 95
12.54.51.108: Event processed 96
12.54.51.108: Event processed 97
12.54.51.108: Event processed 98
12.54.51.108: Event processed 99
12.54.51.108: End
12.54.52.212: Saved checkpoint of : Event - 99
```

Comment: Tested but does not solved my need,  i need OnNext to block until Subscribed method completed

Comment: Then maybe Rx is not the right tool? @OsmanAktemur

Comment: @Fildor maybe :) i am considering that too now

Comment: @OsmanAktemur Did you tried this? I tested this and it works like you described. If I get it wrong - can you please share the expected output?

Comment: @OlegDok i tested it with 3 buffer siz, it logged all "Event processed" 1k times and after that it started to save checkpoint log. But i expected 3 "Event processed" log and wait for 1 sec to finish Checkpoint and then continue another 3

Comment: But maybe i am using Rx for irrelevant requirement

Comment: @OsmanAktemur Please check updated answer with my output. Can you point where it is wrong? Using System.Reactive nuget v6, VS.Code under linux amd64. 

Regarding your point that it is an irrelevant requirement - it is still interesting task for Rx

Comment: @OlegDok i don't know why but i copied all your code to new blank project  and it worked as i wanted,   i missed one point my existing one i think , i'll check it.
Thank you !